# Apply the Hidden behavior on the whole row

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word, ms-office

I have a file with multiple tables and by using the below code I am trying to access the rows which have specific terms using an array.

I successfully select the whole rows but when I try to apply the Hidden behavior on the whole row then VBA through an error.

Getting error on below the line

`Selection.Font.Hidden = True`

Below is my whole code

```
Sub test()
Dim SearchArr() As Variant, Cnt As Integer, Arrcnt As Integer
Dim WrdApp As Object, FileStr As String, WrdDoc As Object, aRng As Range
Dim TblCell As Variant
Set WrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WrdApp.Visible = True

'********** change address to suit
FileStr = "C:\Users\krishna.haldunde\Downloads\DE\DE\International_DE.docx"
Set WrdDoc = WrdApp.Documents.Open(FileStr)

SearchArr = Array("French", "Spanish")
'loop tables
For Cnt = 1 To WrdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
'loop search word
For Arrcnt = LBound(SearchArr) To UBound(SearchArr)
'loop through table cells
For Each TblCell In WrdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(Cnt).Range.Cells

Set aRng = TblCell.Range

'If TblCell.RowIndex = WrdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(Cnt).Rows.Count Then Exit For

If InStr(LCase(aRng), LCase(SearchArr(Arrcnt))) Then

aRng.Select
Selection.Font.Hidden = True

End If

Next TblCell
Next Arrcnt
Next Cnt
End Sub
```

**Can anyone help me out to understand where i am doing issue so, i can rectify it.**

Comment: I assume that your code is placed in an excel workbook. Then `Selection` refers to the excel-selection-object - therefore font doesn't  have the property 'hidden'. You have to use `wrdapp.selection.font.hidden` instead.

Comment: It seems that aRng is just a cell in a Table..  So Instead of "aRng.Select
Selection.Font.Hidden = True" try "aRng.Rows(1).Font.Hidden = True"

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more effective to reduce the row height to an exact minimum value.

Something like this works for me.

```
Sub Test()

    SearchArr = Array("sdg", "sdh", "dsf")
    
    'loop tables
    For Cnt = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
    'loop search word
        For Arrcnt = LBound(SearchArr) To UBound(SearchArr)
        'loop through table cells
            For Each tblCell In ActiveDocument.Tables(Cnt).Range.Cells                
                Set aRng = tblCell.Range                    
                If InStr(LCase(aRng), LCase(SearchArr(Arrcnt))) Then                    
                    ActiveDocument.Tables(Cnt).Rows(tblCell.RowIndex).HeightRule = wdRowHeightExactly
                    ActiveDocument.Tables(Cnt).Rows(tblCell.RowIndex).Height = 1
                End If
            Next tblCell
        Next Arrcnt
    Next Cnt

End Sub
```